# MYSQL Table with 2 columns.Col1 Duplicate ,Col2 unique values

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicate-data

I am using mysql , Table with 2 Columns

```
Col1  |  Col1 
------+-------+
a@a   |   ab  |
a@a   |   cd  |
b@b   |   ab  |
b@b   |   cd  |
```

I want result like this

```
Col1  |  Col1 
------+--------+
a@a   |   abcd |
b@b   |   abcd |
```

How can i achieve this using SQL please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) with no `SEPARATOR` like so:

```
SELECT col1, GROUP_CONCAT(col2 SEPARATOR '') AS col2
FROM tablename
GROUP BY col1;
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3201/1)

This will give you:

```
| COL1 | COL2 |
---------------
|  a@a | abcd |
|  b@b | abcd |
```